# Java on Yosemite

Tags: java, osx-yosemite

My java application cannot open in Yosemite.
the error message like this :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: .../.../view/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.MacLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.run(LaunchRunner.java:116)
    at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.callMain(LaunchRunner.java:51)
    at apple.launcher.JavaApplicationLauncher.launch(JavaApplicationLauncher.java:52)
```

I heard this message occur when the JRE1.7 is not installed.
So I checked the version in my console like this :

```
....-MacBook:~ thrisis$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.10.1
BuildVersion:   14B25
....-MacBook:~ thrisis$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
....-MacBook:~ thrisis$
```

I'm very confused and please help me.

PS, sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

It may also occur is 1.8 is not installed. Make sure you are running the latest versions of Java runtime environment (and Development kit if you need it).

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, but until now I cannot solve it. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by setting my JAVA_HOME

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

In my `.zshrc` file. I use `zsh` shell. You can do the same in your `.bashrc` or `.profile`

You mainly see this error when your "jar" is compiled with a higher `JDK` and you are trying to run it with a lower version. Check out this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, but until now I cannot solve it. :(

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed on your machine?  To find out, go to System Preferences... > Java > General > Java > View...> User Or system. You will see all version of Java installed on your machine.

Comment: there display only java 1.7.0 before, and now, after I installed jre 1.8, there display only java 1.8.0.

Comment: and in the console, $java -version : java version "1.7.0_71" (same before)

Comment: Under `System Preferences... > Java > General > Java > View...> User`, select the which java you want your system to use. Then set java home to point to that location as shown above. Remember to replace version 1.7 with 1.8, if you choose Java 8. Try to lunch your app again.